Can I use CMake to build 2 libraries with a difference based on a generated config file containing a variable
I'm trying to generate to shared libraries with the difference between them is a slight variation in code
, what I had in mind is define a variable using a cmake generated header called ENGINE_TYPE once set to 0 building a library and once set to 1 and building another library, the problem is I think that both libraries end up having the code intended for the second part "foo1"
does cmake generate the files first ie. it generates the first file with ENGINE_TYPE 0 then overwrites it with the second config.h with ENGINE_TYPE 1 and then begins compiling my library so both end up having ENGINE_TYPE 1?
is it feasible to make it work if yes how?
thanks in advance.
# Global Definitions
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MINOR 1)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_PATCH 0)

# Function to configure and build a library
function(configure_and_build_library TARGET_NAME ENGINE_TYPE)
    set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES src/lib/src/my.cpp)
    set(engineType ${ENGINE_TYPE})
    configure_file(include/config.h.in ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/config.h @ONLY)
    add_library(${TARGET_NAME} SHARED ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES})
    target_compile_definitions(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE engineType=${engineType})
    set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES VERSION ${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MAJOR}.${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MINOR}.${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_PATCH} SOVERSION ${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MAJOR})
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY})
endfunction()

# Build valeoengine with engineType 0
set(engineType 0)
configure_and_build_library(foo ${engineType})

# Build valeodecryptengine with engineType 1
set(engineType 1)
configure_and_build_library(foo1 ${engineType})

# Install project
if(NOT SKIP_INSTALL_ALL)
    install(TARGETS foo foo1 LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
endif()


configure_file writes the file at configuration stage. Libraries are built at build stage, which comes after the configuration one. So, when compile a library, compiler sees only the final state of the header file, after all configure_file has been executed. Why do not create different header files for different libraries?

the header only sets the #define which unlocks more modes to a variant and I need the 2 variants of the library built is there a way to do so?

"the header only sets the #define which unlocks more modes" - Then why do not pass additional macro definition for the second library?

Suggestion: add a variant1/config.h and variant2/config.h to your source tree and build the software with a different target_include_directories.
